# how to change mobile page default theme of primefaces

Tags: css, primefaces

Primefaces 5.1 allowed you to create mobile page without adding anything extra by providing mobile page components .and jquery loader provides theme for these mobile pages .
but how to use these theme in mobile pages . Does primefaces mobile component button and all support jquery css classes . ?
how to change theme of these primeface mobile components